# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Flask: How can I send fcm_options link with the message from flask server?

Tags: flask, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase documentation says that link is in the WebpushFcmOptions object, and that object is within the WebpushConfig object.

Here's app.py of flask server:

```
from firebase_admin import messaging
@app.route('/send', methods=['GET'])
def send_push():
    if request.method == "GET":
        # get registration token from wherever you've stored it
        registration_token = ''

        pushlink = "https://myurl.com" # must be https

        message = messaging.Message(
            data={
                'score': '850',
                'time': '2:45',
            },
            token= registration_token,
            webpush = messaging.WebpushConfig(
                fcm_options = messaging.WebpushFcmOptions(
                    link = pushlink
                )
            ),
            notification=messaging.Notification(
                title='New Event',
                body='You have a new event!'
            ),
        )
        
        # send a message to the device corresponding to the provided registration token
        response = messaging.send(message)
        print('Successfully sent message:', response) 
    
    return 'ok'
```

This repeatedly returns the error: messaging doesn't have 'WebpushFcmOptions' attribute.

Tried different variations of the various objects within Firebase REST API documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Instead of webpush = messaging.WebpushFcmOptions(), the "Fcm" must be capitalized.

Correct code:
webpush = messaging.WebpushFCMOptions()

Full correct code:

```
from firebase_admin import messaging
@app.route('/send', methods=['GET'])
def send_push():
    if request.method == "GET":
        # get registration token from wherever you've stored it
        registration_token = ''

        pushlink = "https://myurl.com" # must be https

        message = messaging.Message(
            data={
                'score': '850',
                'time': '2:45',
            },
            token= registration_token,
            webpush = messaging.WebpushConfig(
                fcm_options = messaging.WebpushFCMOptions(
                    link = pushlink
                )
            ),
            notification=messaging.Notification(
                title='New Event',
                body='You have a new event!'
            ),
        )
        
        # send a message to the device corresponding to the provided registration token
        response = messaging.send(message)
        print('Successfully sent message:', response) 
    
    return 'ok'
```